# "unable to resolve dependency tree" getting error in react while installing material-ui/core

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui, npm-install, npm-package

I am using "react": "^18.2.0". In my project I use command to install material-ui

```
npm install @material-ui/core
```

But getting an following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: socialapp@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

any solution for this!!

Comment: Using --legacy-peer-deps is not the best solution. Please post your package.json and node version,